# Most Effective way of fetching data and notating html table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, fetch

I want to notate Stock prices with html table.

The data is come from other REST API server and I'll fetch this data on every 2 seconds.

and The Data will be notate on HTML table and Price Cell also will be updated every 2 seconds.

I coded and It works well, but I have a doubt on this DOM Operation. (seems uneconomic)

My codes work like below:

1. JSON response from the REST API server will be like this:

```json
[
 {"ticker": "stack", "price": "$3.4"},
 {"ticker": "over", "price": "$5.2"},
 {"ticker": "flow", "price": "$6.4"}
]
```

2. HTML table will be like below:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>TICKER</th>
  <th>PRICE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>STACK</td>
  <td id="stackPrice">$3.4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>OVER</td>
  <td id="overPrice">$5.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>FLOW</td>
  <td id="flowPrice">$6.4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

| TICKER | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| STACK | $3.4 |
| OVER | $5.2 |
| FLOW | $6.4 |

3. On this condition, My JavaScript code like below.

```js
function fetchAndNotateData(){
   fetch(apiURL, {
    method: "GET",
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    data.forEach(element => {
     document.getElementById(`${element.ticker}Price`).innerText = element.price; // seems inefficient 
    });
    setTimeout(fetchAndNotateData,2000);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

There is even 100 over tickers to notate in practice.

so There will be many DOM Operation (e.g. *document.getElementById*).

and Giving id on each table price cell seems not that efficient.

Is there any other more effective way of fetching data and notating table?
(maybe I need Server-side Rendering ?)

Comment: Maybe this question is better asked at [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](codereview.stackexchange.com) . Nice to know would also be if the amount of data changes, and what are you doing with it then? Say first request you get those 3 rows, 2 request you get 4 rows but one from the first request is now missing. So remove it, keep it, mark it... ? too many options which are not clear

Comment: The Number of rows (tickers) will be fixed. and order of Response is also same always.  
I want to Just updating Price Cell continuously. So that I can get Real-time Stock Prices(2seconds interval though)
Thank you for answer about codereview.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Remove table contents excluding the header e.g.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>TICKER</th>
  <th>PRICE</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And change your change your ajax to this. Make sure you have jQuery imported

```
data.forEach(element => {

      $( "table" ).append( '<tr><td>'+element.ticker+'</td><td>'+element.price+'</td></tr>' );
           
    });
```